# django wizard - saving separate forms to a single model

Tags: django, forms

I'm using django wizard to have multiple forms (will have several pages of forms in the end). 
I have a single custom user model and I've split the signup into several modelforms (using Meta, fields).  However I'm not clear on django wizard how the `done` method should be setup to save all the data from the forms to a single instance of user?

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    account_number = models.IntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

forms.py

```
class SignupForm(allauthforms.SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

class UserAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['account_name',
                  'account_number',
                  ]
```

views.py

```
SIGNUP_FORMS = [
    ('signup', SignupForm),
    ('direct_debit', UserDirectDebitForm),
]

TEMPLATES = {
    'signup': 'account/signup.html',
    'direct_debit': 'site/directdebit.html',
}

class SignupWizard(SessionWizardView):
       def get_template_names(self):
           return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

       def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
           xxxxxxx
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))

signup_view = SignupWizard.as_view(SIGNUP_FORMS)
```